# jQuery to return the wrapper of the content instead of only the content

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element, return-value

Assume I have the following HTML

```
<articles>

    <article id="a1">
        <!-- Content of article with id="a1" -->
    </article>

    <article id="a2">
        <!-- Content of article with id="a2" -->
    </article>

    <article id="a3">
        <!-- Content of article with id="a3" -->
    </article>

</articles>
```

Using jQuery, I did the following

```
var x = $("#a2").html();
```

Now, the variable `x` will contian:

```
<!-- Content of article with id="a2" -->
```

However, I like to have `x` contain:

```
<article id="a2">
    <!-- Content of article with id="a2" -->
</article>
```

I tried:

```
var x = $("#a2").parent().html();
```

but this returned all three articles, which is not what I want. I only want article **a2**. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) property,

```
var x = $("#a2")[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Why do I have to use index [0]?

Comment: @Greeso Since `.outerHTML` is a property belongs to the element object of plain javascript. we have to get it by reading the element from index 0.

Comment: outerHtml is not a property of jquery it's javascript. var x = documentElementById('a2').outerHTML;